# data not being written to NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data, nsmutablearray

I have an iOS app that pulls data from a server and persists it using CoreData.  I have a UITableView that I am trying to populate with only select portions from a given core data attribute.

Before the table is populated I cycle through the data and pass what I want into a `NSMutableArray`.  The problem is when I find an item I want it is not being added to the array.

I declare the array in my `.h` file like so...

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *theNewSource;
```

And Synthesize it in the `.m` file

```
@synthesize theNewSource = _theNewSource;
```

Here is the method...

```
-(NSMutableArray *)setDataSourceArray
{

    for(int i = 0; i < rcount ; i++)
    {
        NSIndexPath *countingInteger = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:i inSection:0];
        NSManagedObject *object = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:countingInteger];
        NSString *action = [object valueForKey:@"theActionName"];

        if (![action isEqual:@"Login"])
        {            
            [_theNewSource addObject:action];
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"the array is now %@",_theNewSource);
    return _theNewSource;

}
```

I've set a breakpoint in the line `[_theNewSource addObject:action]`.  I can see in the console that the variable `action` does have a value but it is never added to `_theNewSource` array... I'm sure this is Objective C 101 but I can't get it figured out.  Please Help!

Comment: As an aside - this seems like a lot of work, when you could be setting this as a predicate in your NSFetchedResultsController's fetch request.

Comment: Abizern, I had glanced through some of the CoreData Documentation because I thought there was a way to do it with the fetch request but I overlooked the predicate.  Jsdodgers has fixed my issue but I would like to avoid this method if I could.  Could you point me to an example of how to use the predicate.  The CoreData attribute I am pulling from is "theActionName" as you can see.  When I fetch the data from the attribute I just want to leave out the "Login" actions can using the predicate do that?

Comment: Duplicate of about 100 others.  Gotta create the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you even created your `_theNewSource` array? It seems like you haven't done the following:

```
_theNewSource = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Make sure you are creating your instance before trying to use it.

Comment: Wow thats embarrassing!  I tried it once but I formatted it wrong I was trying to create it using `NSMutableArray *_theNewSource`  but it was giving me an error so I deleted it!  That was the trick thanks Jsdodgers!

Comment: @Ben - Note that you should do that in the `init` routine.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a predicate in the NSFetchedResultsController's fetchRequest directly:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"theActionName != %@", @"Login"];
```

NSFetchResultsControllers are particularly useful for driving table views and collection views, so filtering their results to create a separate data source is a code smell.

Doing it this way means that you can use the NSFetchedResultsController directly as the data source for your table instead of using it to create a filtered array to act as the datasource.

Comment: Abizern this is what I was looking for all along.  I've implemented this and am using it now.  This is much easier than creating a new array.  I posted another question on how to filter data as the table was populated and received multiple suggestions to create a separate array and use that as the datasource.  This is a much better way to accomplish my needs in my opinion!  Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad it helped.  It's why I prefer to solve the actual problem rather than just answering the question directly.